# How to import an old email database into eM Client?

Tags: email, data-recovery, import

My last windows install got utterly corrupted, so I could only save the direct files from appdata/roaming/eM Client. Among these files, is a huge email database (mail_data.dat).

However, from what I can tell there is no direct way to import this into a new install of eM client, and the file structure of the newer version is different enough that I can't simply replace the files in the new install...

Does anyone know of a way to recover these emails, preferably by importing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a good ton of tinkering, the solution turned out to be to downgrade my version of eM Client to one that still used the old database file structure.

From there, I could simply replace the database file of the new install with the old database file.

Finally, I then upgraded eM Client to the newest version. This also updated the database file structure while preserving the data.